# Crystal Reports: Conditional Background color

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using this formula in order to color the background of my cells (My cells are summary, maximum of a certain field).

`if (CurrentFieldValue = "") then crRed else crGray`

I placed this formula, on right click, format, Border, Background (x-2).

However my cell is neither coloring red, nor gray.

My SQL-server query is not returning null values. I always use: `ISNULL(Fld1, '')`

Comment: Maybe you set the formula for border instead of background accidentially?

Comment: no borders either are colored.

Comment: The default setting for the left/right/top/bottom line is "None", thus setting the bordercolor has no effect without changing these. I've tested your formula and it works, so I guessed that it's set in the wrong place.

Comment: I understand you said the query is not returning null, but even tought, please, try: if isnull(CurrentFieldValue) OR CurrentFieldValue = "" then crRed else crGray. If it still does not work, may you post a screenshot of your real formula and your design?

Comment: but i didn't color the border, (x-2) was set on the background. 
did you test it with empty string?

Comment: @heringer isnull(CurrentFieldValue) returns an error